Excel auto translate using VBA and Spanishdict.com, NOT Google Translate
I've seen different ways to translate one cell into another language. I'm looking for VBA coding to do this using spanishdict.com, not Google Translate. Google Translate works great, but uses Castilian Spanish and I need Mexican Spanish translations.
I'm a teacher and this is for a progress report I built using Excel.
I need to be able to translate comments for parents.
I'm currently using this VBA module coding that I found here (Thank you, whoever wrote this!).
Anyway to modify this for spanishdict.com?
Function Translate$(sText$, FromLang$, ToLang$)
    Dim p1&, p2&, url$, resp$
    Const DIV_RESULT$ = "<div class=""result-container"">"
    Const URL_TEMPLATE$ = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=[from]&sl=[from]&tl=[to]&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q="
    url = URL_TEMPLATE & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(sText)
    url = Replace(url, "[to]", ToLang)
    url = Replace(url, "[from]", FromLang)
    resp = WorksheetFunction.WebService(url)
    p1 = InStr(resp, DIV_RESULT)
    If p1 Then
        p1 = p1 + Len(DIV_RESULT)
        p2 = InStr(p1, resp, "</div>")
        Translate = Mid$(resp, p1, p2 - p1)
    End If
End Function

Thanks in advance.
I am trying to translate English to Mexican Spanish. Castilian Spanish is close but the translation could be closer for my students' parents.

"..coding that I found here (Thank you, whoever wrote this!)" - possibly unanswered post optimize code for speed that .. translate excel sheet using regex ..?

I don't see any url parameterization at that spanishdict.com website, nor do I see any way to interact with it programatically besides potentially automating and scraping, which is going to take a lot of code, likely violates their TOS, and is going to be super slow.

Not sure if you still see comments from review, so: looks like DIV_RESULT$ = "<a href=""/translate/ and URL_TEMPLATE$ = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/" may be a start. Then you'll see if the result contains the translation, and do further cleanup with InStr+Mid$.
